# create a nodelet launch file

Tags: ros, roscpp, pluginlib, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to build a nodelet (tegra_stereo) and it is detected when I run "rospack plugins --attrib=plugin nodelet"

```
 image_view /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/image_view/nodelet_plugins.xml
 image_proc /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/image_proc/nodelet_plugins.xml
 image_rotate /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/image_rotate/nodelet_plugins.xml
 image_publisher /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/image_publisher/nodelet_plugins.xml
 stereo_image_proc /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/stereo_image_proc/nodelet_plugins.xml
 depth_image_proc /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/image_pipeline/depth_image_proc/nodelet_plugins.xml
 tegra_stereo /home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/tegra_stereo/nodelet_plugins.xml
 pointgrey_camera_driver/home/ashwath/catkin_ws/src/pointgrey_camera_driver/pointgrey_camera_driver/nodelet_plugins.xml
```

I want to run the nodelet. I couldn't find any helpful tutorial to do that. How do I start the nodelet? Or how to call the nodelet on another ros program?

**Update 2**
I could launch the nodelet using the following launch file.

```
<launch>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager"/>
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="tegra" args="load tegra_stereo/tegra_stereo_proc 
standalone_nodelet" output="screen">
 </node>          
</launch>
```

This is what I get on rqt_graph
[image: standalone_nodelet doesn't connect to tegra_stereo]
**standalone_nodelet doesn't connect to tegra_stereo**

This is on my rostopic list

```
/clock
/kitti_stereo/left/camera_info 
/kitti_stereo/left/image_rect
/kitti_stereo/right/camera_info
/kitti_stereo/right/image_rect
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/standalone_nodelet/bond
/statistics
/stereo/cam0/image_rect
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressed
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressedDepth
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/theora
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/cam0/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/stereo/cam1/image_rect
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressed
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressed/parameter_descriptions
```

/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressed/parameter_updates
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressedDepth
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/theora
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/theora/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/cam1/image_rect/theora/parameter_updates
/stereo/disparity
/stereo/disparity_raw
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressed
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressedDepth
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/disparity_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/stereo/disparity_raw/theora
/stereo/disparity_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/stereo/disparity_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/tf

The nodelet subscribes to the following topics but it does not work for me. There are no messages on the /stereo topics.
Any insights on doing this?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263507/create-a-nodelet-launch-file/) by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-09**:
What does rostopic info /kitti_stereo/left/image_rect and rostopic info /kitti_stereo/right/image_rect show?  Also what does rosnode info on the rosbag node show?

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-09**:
Subscirbers : None for both left and right.
Node [/play_1497032227332749755]
rosnode info for the bag shows the default rosbag services and the publications of the rosbag. Connection is with /rosout only

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-09**:
@lucasw, i added the update to the quesiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet/Tutorials/Running%20a%20nodelet has a copy of this example nodelet launch file https://github.com/ros/common_tutorials/blob/indigo-devel/nodelet_tutorial_math/plus.launch

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-09**:
Yes, I have tried this. It launches the nodelet. I am not able to communicate with it. The nodelet subscribes to 2 image topics. When I play the rosbag with the 2 image topics, I can see the topics on rostopic list, but no output from the nodelet as no connection forms between the bag and nodelet

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-09**:
Do you have a nodelet manager running?

```
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="standalone_nodelet"  args="manager"/>
```

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-06-09**:
I did that. It connects the nodes now. But one of the nodes dies. "[standalone_nodelet-2] process has died [pid 27763, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=standalone_nodelet" I don't understand the error

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-12**:
You could make a new question that is focused on the tegra_stereo nodelet (and has that in the title so people familiar with it can see it).  Other than that you would have to debug the nodelet yourself http://answers.ros.org/question/35171/how-to-debug-nodelet-manager-crashes/

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-06-12**:
Also check the tegra_stereo github page for alternate branches or more up to date versions to try out.